# Create a list that has (9 ) dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have stuck ,basically I am not sure if the result is this in R studio.
I have an excel and I have import it inside the R studio.
What I want to do is to use the function split() so I will create a list which will have 9 types of dataframe , each one of every sport. Example (C1,C2..,C9).

what I did was:

> to do split(C1) and to press Run. After I wrote the next. split(C2)
> and goes on.Did I solve it right?

edited: I have one column ,name is  sport. On the sport column I have many C1 ,many C2 many C3 and goes on until C9. There is a big excell.
I must create a list of each one C.
list 1 for example will be C1.
list 2 will be C2 and goes on.
I must use split function to create the list with  dataframe of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can read the data first and `split` the column into a `list` of data.frames

```
library(readxl)
df1 <- read_excel('path/to/file')
lst1 <- split(df1, df1$sport)
names(lst1) <- paste0("C", seq_along(lst1))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(sport = sample(paste0("C", 1:9), 100, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: I have read those   "library(readxl)
df1 <- read_excel('path/to/file')", after that I mean this part lst1 <- split(df1, df1$colnm)
names(lst1) <- paste0("C", seq_along(lst1)) ,it doesn't match..something goes wrong

Comment: @maikl The `colnm` should be your actual column name on which the splitting is done

Comment: @maikl what is the column name of your column you want to split

Comment: the column name is sport- I mean in sport there are the names C1 ,C2 etc in different rows each one of those C1,C2 until C9

Comment: So the step would be `lst1 <- split(df1, df1$sport)`

Comment: I must create for each C1 ,C2 ,C3 etc a list. Not only lst1..

Comment: what are C1, C2, C3 .. are those the column names

Comment: @maikl try the updatd

Comment: NO,there are inside the column sport

Comment: @maikl if those are column values.  then `split(df1, df1$sport)` create a list of data.frames

Comment: There are inside the column sport and I want to to create a list for each one of C1 ,C2 ,C3

Comment: @maikl if you can update your post iwth a small example and expected, it is easier to understasnd

Comment: It is not clear to me.  Because the code I showed is to split the column 'sport' based on the values in that

Comment: Your description is `so I will create a list which will have 9 types of dataframe , each one of every sport.`  the split in my code is doing that

Comment: @maikl yes, i did.  If your dataset is `df1 <- data.frame(sport = c('C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C3', 'C2'))` the code works i.e. `split(df1, df1$sport)`

Comment: does exist another solution to it?

Comment: @maikl yes, you can also do `lapply(unique(df1$sport), function(x) subset(df1, sport == x))`